# Can my PC handle Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, wubi

i am new to ubuntu and the linux world generally ! i am trying to install kubuntu 18.04 on my old desktop computer ( however this is my main machine ) the machine has 1GB of RAM and a 1.80 GHZ amd proccesor and 15GB of free disk space so can i install and run kubuntu on this computer and is it possible to install it with wubi because i want the easy way. and thank you

Comment: Please avoid wubi. Since several years It is no longer supported.

Answer (score 3):

You should try a look at [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.me) it is for older pc. Since 18.04 Kubuntu does not support 32-bit anymore you should install Lubuntu instead of Kubuntu

EDIT:
All Ubuntu flavours supports 32-bit but KDE Plasma 5 won't run smooth on your device because the hardware is too old.

Comment: +1. **I agree about Lubuntu for this older PC.** But Kubuntu has released a 32-bit iso file. As a matter of fact, all Ubuntu *community flavours* are still providing and supporting 32-bit versions (of the current 18.04 LTS). You can find them via this link: [releases.ubuntu.com/](http://releases.ubuntu.com/). But Standard Ubuntu Desktop and Ubuntu Server are only released as 64-bit versions.

Comment: Okay I didn't know that the flavours are still providing 32-bit images without Lubuntu. I will edit my answer

Comment: The question is about 18.04 LTS and we have been talking about 18.04 LTS. Things will change with 'Cosmic' to be released as 18.10 in October. The [QA testing tracker](http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/390/builds) offers 32-bit iso files for Lubuntu and Xubuntu. We can expect that the other community flavours (including Kubuntu) will release only 64-bit iso files. In addition there will be a 32-bit `mini.iso` alias Netboot and a 32-bit Ubuntu Base.